# Is it possible to add a computer to Firefox Sync if I have my already configured Android phone with me?

Tags: sync, firefox-for-android

Is it possible to add a computer to Firefox Sync if I have my already configured Android phone with me?

All the online tutorials cover the case where your computer is configured and you want to add your android phone to sync, but phone -> computer is much more useful since the phone is the thing you carry with you. I haven't been able to find the option in Firefox Mobile, is it at all possible?